# How do I make a Cypress Alias work between test cases?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, cypress, e2e-testing

I am getting inconsistent behaviour when using aliases in Cypress. I think it may be down to something with asynchronous behaviour between test cases.

From the [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Aliases) I tried both methods of referencing the Alias.

#### With 'this'

```js
    it(`When clicks on an entry from the list`, () => {
        cy.get(`tr`)
            .eq(2)
            .within(() => {
                cy.get(':nth-child(1)')
                    .invoke('text')
                    .as(`etaId`)
                    .then(() =>
                        cy.get(':nth-child(1)')
                            .click()
                            .then(() => cy.wait(100))

                    )
            })
    })

    it(`Then ETA details are shown`, () => {

        cy.contains(`ETA: ${this.etaId}`)
            .should(`be.visible`)
    })
```

Gives the error

> Cannot read property 'etaId' of undefined

#### With 'cy.get(`@{alias}`).then()'

```js
    it(`When clicks on an entry from the list`, () => {
        cy.get(`tr`)
            .eq(2)
            .within(() => {
                cy.get(':nth-child(1)')
                    .as(`etaIdCell`)
                    .invoke('text')
                    .as(`etaId`)
                    .then(() =>
                        cy.get(':nth-child(1)')
                            .click()
                            .then(() => cy.wait(100))

                    )
            })
    })

    
    it(`Then ETA details are shown`, () => {
        cy.get(`@etaId`)
            .then(id => {
                cy.contains(`ETA: ${id}`)
                    .should(`be.visible`)
            })
    })
```

I know that the selector for the alias is correct because the following code when I do everything in the same test case works correctly

```js
      it(`When clicks on an entry from the list`, () => {
        cy.get(`tr`)
            .eq(2)
            .within(() => {
                cy.get(':nth-child(1)')
                    .invoke('text')
                    .as(`etaId`)
                    .then(() =>
                        cy.get(':nth-child(1)')
                            .click()
                            .then(() => cy.wait(100)
                    )
            )
        })
        .then(() => {
            cy.get(`@etaId`)
                .then(id => {
                    cy.contains(`ETA: ${id}`)
                        .should(`be.visible`)
                })
        })
    })
```

and I can see in the dev tools

[image]

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're right. Your alias syntax is correct; but in the one case your alias is encapsulated in one of the it blocks and when the test is complete, it loses the context of the `etaId`. You'd have to set the alias in a `beforeEach` block or in a shared scope so that your test can see it.

Comment: What if I don't want to run this before each test case? I have in this file many tests cases and it only relates to these two cases. If i did run it in the 'beforeEach' hook the elements of the UI may not be in the correct state to get the data causing the tests to break. I thought the whole point of aliases was to get around this problem of sharing scope between cases. It almost seems worth going against the docs and jus declaring a global variable in the file and using that at this point!

Comment: We you're declaring the alias within a scope; I'm not sure why you would think it would be able to transcend one scope and be accessible within another. Where in the documentation did you get that idea?

Your best bet is going to be going with the promise chain and accessing it in the `then` block. If its only two `it`s it shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: I thought through the Cypress api these values where stored there globally. As Cypress is available globally I thought this would be possible to store values there through the alias function. It would definitely come in handy